# Automatic mouse pointer color change

Tags: 16.04, mouse, themes, mate

I have two Ubuntu MATE 16.04 PC in which the mouse pointer automatically contrast with the background, it means the mouse cursor appears white (DMZ White or MATE theme) against a dark background but black (DMZ Black) against a white or bright background. That is fine to me but now I have installed Ubuntu MATE from scratch in another computer and I am not able to find a way to reproduce the same behavior for the mouse pointer. I don't remember what I modified or which application I have installed in order to get it.

How may I get it in the new computer?

Thanks in advance